# How do you create a constant to grow a number uniformly?

Tags: programming, constants

My background is computer programming. I am attempting to generate a single number for a mask at compile time, as I know all the parameters for the equation. However, I am struggling to output this brain teaser. Back when I was dealing with fixed point numbers, I was trying to do something similar - which was create a constant which essentially shifts its place value leaving numbers behind, but is also variable.

This is a pretty high level question. I am 100% certain I have seen the answer to my question before in a random place, however, I no longer have access to it.

Goal: Create a number that duplicates a number over several place values.

---

## Correct Conventional Ways

```
size_t getmask(size_t num_of_bytes) {
    size_t out = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<num_of_bytes; i++) {
        out <<= 0x100;
        out |= 0xFF;
    }
    return out;
}
```

```
constexpr unsigned mask(unsigned N) { return unsigned(~(-1<<N)); }
```

```
constexpr unsigned int mask = ((unsigned int) -1) >> (N * 8);
```

```
constexpr unsigned int mask = (0xFFFFFFFF) >> (N * 8);
```

---

## What I have tried

At first I thought I could generate a sequence, which could be dynamically made. My inputs where 0xFF (255) and I needed a sequence of 0x1010100 + 0x1. When 0xFF * 0x1010101, you get 0xFFFFFFFF. This is brilliant and exactly what I need - shifting the current value over and leaving a value behind. I discovered that I only translated the problem over to then generating a sequence of 0x1010 for a final number of 0x1010100 to add 0x1 to.

```
printf("%8.8X", 0xFF * 0x1010101);
-> 0xFFFFFFFF
```

The second runner up was trying to create a sequence like 0x10101. I decided to try using powers and using a trick to shift the place values. 0xFF * 0x10 = 0xFF0, which is similar to that in base10 as, 25 * 10 = 250. So I noted that I can shift the place value by raising 0x10 by a power of the place value. The piece I am missing is placing the value back down in its tread.

```
printf("%8.8X", 0xFF * pow(0x10, 2));
-> 0x0000FF00
printf("%8.8X", 0xFF * pow(0x10, 3));
-> 0x000FF000
printf("%8.8X", 0xFF * pow(0x10, 4));
-> 0x00FF0000
```

So I attempted to use 0x101 as the shifter, as I noted that at the end of the sequence 0x1010100 I needed a 1 there. So I plugged in 0x101 into power, but I was unfortunate to gather a rather invalid (but certainly almost correct) sequence.

```
printf("%8.8X", pow(0x101, 1));
-> 0x00000101
printf("%8.8X", pow(0x101, 2));
-> 0x00010201
printf("%8.8X", pow(0x101, 3));
-> 0x01030301
```

The two and threes that are embedded into the sequence makes it impossible for my 0xFF constant to be multiplied and create 0xFF, 0xFFFF, and 0xFFFFFF in this situation.

---

Finally, I am at a loss of what to try next. What I am expecting is `0xFF * some_number * N` which when N is 1 = 0xFF, N is 2 = 0xFFFF, N is 3 = 0xFFFFFF, etc. So I am reaching my hands to the math experts of the time to shed some light.

Sorry this question is kind of identity crisis, but I am having a lot of trouble verbalizing what I am looking for due to lack of words to describe it.

Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You say you want to create a mask at compile time, but not what conditions this mask has to satisfy.  Also, as stated this seems to be a programming problem.  Perhaps it would be better to post it on stack overflow.

Comment: The conditions this mask has to satisfy is arbitrary. The goal is to create a sequence of numbers with close respect to place value. Basically shifting over two place values and duplicating a number, without a for loop. I considered asking stack overflow, but as it is more of a math question than a programming question (I chose to use programming to represent my examples instead of pure math symbols), I decided to refrain. I am not good with those.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say the conditions are arbitrary.  That's the same as saying there are no conditions.  Also, as soon as you mention `for` loops, it sounds like a programming problem to me.  Can you restate it as a math problem sonehow?

Comment: For loops, or summations. Sure can, 25 * 100 = 2500, but how do I calculate N: 25 * N = 2525? More importantly, 25 * N = 252525 also. It would happen to be 101 and 10101. How can I generate such a sequence?

Comment: @user2262111 If $25*N = 2525$ then you compute $N = 2525/25$. Is this what you are asking? I can't tell at all what you are trying to ask. When you say "How can I generate such a sequence?", what kind of a sequence are you talking about?

Comment: I am trying to find a method of taking an input N, and creating a series of 10's ending in 1 (101) to satisfy duplicating D , 'N' amount of times. So when D = 2, and N = 12 I get DD or 1212, thusly when D = 99 and N = 5 I get DDDDD or 9999999999.

Comment: I realized I messed up my last comment pretty horribly. 
I am trying to find a method of taking an input N, and creating a series of 10's ending in 1 (101) to satisfy duplicating N , D amount of times. So when D = 2, and N = 12 I get NN or 1212, thusly when D = 5 and N = 99 I get NNNNN or 9999999999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. It just needed clever thinking.

I needed to generate a number such as 0x10101, so that I could multiply 0xNN to the number and receive 0xNNNNNN. Naturally, my first instinct was right - using powers.

In base10, the formula would be `(((pow(10.0, 2.0 * (N - 1))) / 99))` where 10 is the base, `10^2n` is the formula for base10 place value adjustment, N is the number of requested sequences of 10's, and 99 is the max place value that can fit in 2.0 place values. In base16, the formula would be `(((pow(16.0, 2.0 * (N - 1))) / 0xFF))`. If I wanted to adjust either of these equations to use even more place values, I would alter 2.0 and increase the number of 9's in 99 to match the alteration. The same would be in hexadecimal.